# User authentication via curl request

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I've got same login page for every CRM.

These are the steps:

1. Enter password and login
2. Send curl to CRM on crm.dev/api/auth/check with user data, which checks if user exists in CRM
3. CRM returns success if user exists, after this authenticates user via Auth::user('user_data_here') and redirects to main page of CRM

My problem is that auth doesn't work. And no user data is stored in session (because of previous problem).

CRM auth code:

```
public function checkUserExists(Request $request)
{
    $this->redirectIfAuthorized();

    $user = User::find($request->uid);
    if ($user) {
        return ['response' => 'LOGIN_SUCCESS'];
    }
    return ['response' => 'DB_ERROR'];
}

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);
    $user = User::find($request->uid);
    $user->remember_token = $request->token;
    if ($user->update()) {
        Auth::login($user, true);
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    } else {
        return redirect($this->redirectAfterLogout);
    }
}

public function redirectIfAuthorized()
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return redirect($this->redirectTo);
    }
}
```

Api route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::post('check', 'LoginController@checkUserExists');
    Route::get('login', 'LoginController@login');
    Route::get('logout', 'LoginController@logout');
});
```

And login page's logic for this CURL request

```
private function sendToken($action, $user, $token)
{
    $query = DB::table('user_base')->join('bases', 'bases.id', '=', 'user_base.base_id')
                                   ->where('user_base.user_id', $user);

    $result = $query->get();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $urlAPI = $row->url_api;
        if ($urlAPI == 'http://appliance.dev/api/auth') {
            $urlAPI .= '/check';
        }
        $rsp = $this->curl($urlAPI, array(
            'apiKey' => $this->apiKey,
            $action => true,
            'uid' => $row->base_uid,
            'token' => $token
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use routing in `web.php` file instead of `api.php`